# Ignoring Button Clicks without Disabling Button

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm looking for a way to ignore clicks on a `Button` without actually flipping it to `IsEnabled="False"` since disabling the button lightens it, making it inconsistent with the rest of my UI. Is this possible? Or is it perhaps possible to override the lightened style that is applied for that single button when disabled?

Comment: Why would you need to show the button like it's enabled when clearly it should be disabled. Then How would you inform the user that the button  click does nothing?
As far as your question goes, you can maintain a flag to keep track of when to execute button click and when not to. In your button click event you can check this flag and decide the next action.

Comment: Sometimes, you have to do that. Solve the problem and not questioning it is wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `IsHitTestVisible` property that you can set to `False`:

```
<Button Content="..." IsHitTestVisible="False" />
```

This will make the `Button` "unclickable".

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, and is the preferable answer since it prevents even the cursor from changing appearance on hover over.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply register your Click event in codebehind somewhere in loaded or constructor like:

```
MyButton.Click += Button_Clicked
```

and when you dont want to execute just unregister it

```
MyButton.Click -= Button_Clicked
```

Or using **Commands**
just return false from CanExecute Method 
See [Command](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/using-relaycommand-icommand-to-handle-events-in-wpf-and-mvvm/) here

Or Just use a flag in Click event to return if condition is met

Comment: If CanExecute = false then the button will be disabled.